# Three vertices of a parallelogram have coordinates (-2,2),(1,6) and (4,3). Find all possible coordinates of the fourth vertex.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Do I use the distance formula for the two points and use them to add to each other to get two parallel sides?

Comment: Use the fact that diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other.... so the midpoints of both the diagonals would coincide.

Answer (score 3):

If three points are $P,Q,R$ then $R+(P-Q)$ gives a fourth vertex for a parallelogram. So pick the ordered pair $(P,Q)$ in all six ways, and that gives three parallelograms.

There are actually only three such paralellograms, some using my description being repeats (same vertices). So if $P,Q,R$ are the three given points (which are not collinear) the three parallelograms are those formed by using the given three vertices along with any one of the three choices $$P+Q-R,\ P+R-Q,\ Q+R-P$$ as the fourth vertex of the parallelogram.

*Added note:* In each case the subtracted point winds up being diagonally opposite the constructed point in that parallelogram. For example, if $X=P+Q-R,$ then also $X-P=Q-R$ as expected in a parallelogram labeled going around say counterclockwise in the order $X,P,R,Q.$ The equality of the vectors $X-P$ and $Q-R$ means they are parallel and point in the same direction, so that side $XP$ is parallel to side $QR.$ And also from $X=P+Q-R$ we get $X-Q=P-R$ showing the other pair $XQ,PR$ are parallel (the remaining pair of parallel sides of that parallelogram). Suggest draw a picture to see why for this case each of $XR$ and $PQ$ wind up as "diagonals" of the parallelogram formed.

Comment: I am looking for 2 coordinates on the fourth point of one parallelogram

Comment: @HamTheEpicಠ_ಠ: Read the answer given by coffeemath, he has already given it.  In that answer $P+Q$ means co-ordinatewise addition.

Answer (score -1):

Here, Three points are given,

$P(-2,\;2)$

$Q(1,\;6)$

$R(4,\;3)$

and take $S(x,\;y)$

Since in parallelogram

$\vec{PS}=\vec{QR}$,

Therefore,
$$(Sx−Px,Sy−Py)=(Rx−Qx,Ry−Qy)$$
$$⇒(x−(−2),y−2)=(4−1,3−6)$$
$$⇒x−(−2)=4-1\;\;\implies x=0$$ 
 $$⇒y−2=3−6\;\;\implies y=-1$$

Thus, coordinates of fourth vertex are $S(0,\;-1)$

I hope it' ll help.

Comment: This is only one instance of the possibles.

Comment: Yes, it is the exact point of the given parallelogram.

Comment: Deepak, what user Mick means is that, given the three points, there are more than one way to pick a fourth (in fact three ways) point to form a parallelogram with the given three in it.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes. You can form what looks like 4 triangles on a grid which is 3 parallelograms. I just don't know how to solve the ones ones outside of what I know or is logical on a grid.

Comment: Draw the initial 3 **fixed** points. Then add the 4th such that they form a parallelogramm. How many such parallelograms can be drawn?

Comment: @HamTheEpic I'll add an explanation in my answer above, the subtracted point in each case winds up being diagonally opposite the vertex expressed.

Comment: the coordinates should be b1,-1

Answer (score -1):

***SIMPLE***

diagonals of a parallelogram bisect each other.SO in here $o$ will be the midpoint

[image]